# Good antivirus for Terminal Services environment (Windows Server 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, anti-virus, windows-terminal-services

I'm looking for  a good antivirus to install on a Windows Server 2008 with Terminal Services enabled and 10 concurrent user that run app on this server through app remote ...
This server is in a simply Workgroup network, and i want to install on it a good antivirus compatible with terminal  services enviroment.

Some time ago in another similar server i've found installed NOD32 but this antivirus create a process for every terminal services users that log on, i want to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a good experience in the past with [Trend Micro Server Protect](http://us.trendmicro.com/us/products/enterprise/serverprotect-for-microsoft-windows/).

Creates a silent system services on the server & has backend management tools.

Answer (score 0):

[AVG Business Edition](http://www.avg.com/us-en/product-avg-anti-virus-business-edition) works well and only creates processes for the system, not for each user logged on to the TS.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to limit everyone's AV engine to one process?
That would slow everyone down and they'd have to wait for that one overburdened process to scan all the user-generated I/O.

Multiple processes have a better shot at distributing the load across cores, thus giving users a more responsive workspace.

At least Kaspersky has a server version that allows you to create multiple processes per user, to make use of multicore. It's the only one I've heard of that allows that.